# sql presence specific date valid from and valid to records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I'm working on for presence control. The check-in and check-out are **2 difference records in a table**

It is possible that somebody does not check-out for several days, but should count as present for the particular day

```
person ID  -       CheckIn                   - CheckOut

3842     12/17/2022 09:030  --   never check out (should count every day after 12/17.2022 as well)

3843     12/17/2022 08:00  --   12/17/2022 09:30.   (same day below)

3843     12/17/2022 11:00  --   12/17/2022 13:30.   (same day above)

3841     12/17/2022 08:00  --   12/17/2022 17:45.   (simple same day)

3844     12/17/2022 22:00  --   12/18/2022 6:40.   (crosses midnight - should count 12/17 and 12/18)

I would expect following result

12/15 1 peron
12/17 4 persons 
12/18 2 persons
```

I want to see how many have been present on day X

I am a little bit stuck how to do it with 2 different records (check-in and check-out) or only 1 recrods available ()check-in

```
CREATE TABLE `my_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `when_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Some insert statements

```
INSERT INTO `my_history` ( `person_id`, `action`, `when_created`)
VALUES
    ( 3842, 'checked_in', '2022-12-15 08:00:00'),
    ( 3842, 'checked_out', '2022-12-15 09:30:00'),
    ( 3842, 'checked_in', '2022-12-17 09:30:00'),
    ( 3843, 'checked_in', '2022-12-17 08:00:00'),
    ( 3843, 'checked_out', '2022-12-17 09:30:00'),
    ( 3843, 'checked_in', '2022-12-17 11:00:00'),
    ( 3843, 'checked_out', '2022-12-17 13:30:00'),
    ( 3841, 'checked_in', '2022-12-17 08:00:00'),
    ( 3841,  'checked_out', '2022-12-17 17:42:00'),
    ( 3844, 'checked_in', '2022-12-17 22:00:00'),
    ( 3844,  'checked_out', '2022-12-18 06:40:00');




CREATE TABLE person (
  id    INT(11)
)

INSERT INTO
  person
VALUES
  (3841),
  (3842),
  (3843),
  (3844)
```

Comment: I assume you also have a person table?

Comment: Is this MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8?

Comment: Yes the person join table. I have added it from your example.  I did add some more use cases as well. I think with those example above the correct result should be like 4 for 12/17 and 2 for 12/18  I did play with your fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/Sz2xcziG and did some adjustments on the test data. Trying to get my head around to see the problem

Comment: You need to be very clear and ***specific*** about your requirements. Make an example that covers all scenarios you'd need to cover and give the exact results you'd need; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) It doesn't help that your first example does NOT match the test data you subsequently supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old answer removed as requirement changed.  In rush,  no time to explain it.

```
SELECT
  param.check_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)
FROM
(
  SELECT timestamp '2022-12-15 00:00'   AS check_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT timestamp '2022-12-17 00:00'   AS check_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT timestamp '2022-12-18 00:00'   AS check_date  
)
  AS param
CROSS JOIN
  person       AS p
INNER JOIN
  my_history   AS h
    ON
      h.person_id = p.id
    AND
      h.when_created
      >=
      COALESCE(
        (
          SELECT when_created
            FROM my_history
           WHERE person_id = p.id
             AND when_created <= check_date
        ORDER BY when_created DESC
           LIMIT 1
        ),
        check_date
      )
    AND
      h.when_created < check_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND
      h.action = 'checked_in'
GROUP BY
  param.check_date
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/RXx0x9xt

Comment: I converted it to MS SQL as well and will post it below

Comment: @JensH Why did you tag `MySQL`, if you're using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Hi @MatBailie I use both. So yes I should have tagged maybe both. Thank you for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

Normally to test for this case you would see if the date you were interested in was greater than the checkin date and less than the checkout date.  eg

```
WHERE checkin <= '2022-12-14' and
      checkout >= '2022-12-14'
```

To solve the case where checkout can be null and still be "OK" we just replace null with a value that will satisfy the condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_history
WHERE checkin <= '2022-12-14' and
      COALESCE(checkout,'2022-12-14') >= '2022-12-14'
```

Comment: In and out are on separate rows (timeseries / event log). The version where they're on the same row was to demonstrate the logic required. Check the inserts at the end of the op. Also, check in at the end of the day is meant to count as present for that Whole date.

Comment: @MatBailie -- dang that was not clear -- I assumed the example data was example data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MatBailie that is great.

I additional converted it to MS SQL as well.

MySql

```
SELECT
  param.check_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)
FROM
(
  SELECT timestamp '2022-12-15 00:00'   AS check_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT timestamp '2022-12-17 00:00'   AS check_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT timestamp '2022-12-18 00:00'   AS check_date  
)
  AS param
CROSS JOIN
  person       AS p
INNER JOIN
  my_history   AS h
    ON
      h.person_id = p.id
    AND
      h.when_created
      >=
      COALESCE(
        (
          SELECT when_created
            FROM my_history
           WHERE person_id = p.id
             AND when_created <= check_date
        ORDER BY when_created DESC
           LIMIT 1
        ),
        check_date
      )
    AND
      h.when_created < check_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND
      h.action = 'checked_in'
GROUP BY
  param.check_date
```

MS SQL

```
SELECT
  param.check_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)
FROM
(
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-12-15 00:00', 102) check_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-12-17 00:00', 102) check_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-12-18 00:00', 102) check_date
)
  AS param
CROSS JOIN
  person       AS p
INNER JOIN
  my_history   AS h
    ON
      h.person_id = p.id
    AND
      h.when_created
      >=
      COALESCE(
        (
          SELECT TOP (1) when_created
            FROM my_history
           WHERE person_id = p.id
             AND when_created <= check_date
        ORDER BY when_created DESC
        ),
        check_date
      )
    AND
      h.when_created <  DATEADD(day, 1, param.check_date)
    AND
      h.action = 'checked_in'
GROUP BY
  param.check_date
```

Comment: Example of why the specific RDBMS is important; SQL Server can use APPLY; https://dbfiddle.uk/-AbBiQuY